# Error: Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, variables, syntax, stack

When I tried the code below, I found there's a problem

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'name' was
> corrupted

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char name[1];
    cout << "Input：";
    cin >> name;
    cout << (int)name << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char name[1];` is too small. It allows for 1 character of storage. Since even a 1 character string takes two characters there's nothing you can input that won't overflow the array bounds.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Now it works! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Interestingly it looks like C++20 [changed the behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) for `operator>>` to avoid the UB here.

Comment: [`using namespace std` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).